# Routing laravel conflict

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have to config route to respond to this url:

- /SomeStaticString
- /{category}/{id}

To do this i wrote this code in the web.php file:

```
Route::get('/SomeStaticString','PagesController@SomeStaticString');
Route::get('/{main_category}/{slug}','PagesController@getArticle')->where('main_category', '^(?!SomeStaticString$).*');
```

Is this the right way to handle these url?
If I have to add other url "SomeStaticString" to my application what is the best route implementation?

Comment: Did you mean `->where('main_category', '^(?!addClickBanner$).*');` ? If `id_banner` is a digit, and `slug` is not, you can just constrain `id_banner` with `[0-9]+`

Comment: Using only route parameters, such as in Route::get('/{main_category}/{slug}'...) will grab every uri if the uri is not explicitly stated before this route.

Comment: You should put a route like `/{main_category}/{slug}` below every route you care about. A new route like `SomeStaticString` should be placed above this route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always want to make sure that static routes are defined before wildcard ones because otherwise the router will mistake a static route as a wilcard. Heres a quick example:

```
//This will work
Route::get('foo', ' YourController@foo');
Route::get('{bar}', 'YourController@bar');

//In this order, foo will never get called
Route::get('{bar}', 'YourController@bar');    
Route::get('foo', ' YourController@foo');
```

When you start add more segments to your path, you always want to keep wildcards at the back of their respective sub-groups. This is how a progressively growing route tree should be ordered.

```
//This is good
Route::get('foo', ' YourController@foo');
Route::get('foo/bar', ' YourController@bar');
Route::get('foo/{id}', 'YourController@foobar');
Route::get('foo/bar/stuff', 'YourController@extrafoobar');
Route::get('foo/bar/{id}', 'YourController@megafoobar');
Route::get('foo/{bar}/stuff', 'YourController@uberfoobar');
Route::get('foo/{bar}/{id}', 'YourController@finalfoobar');
```

For your case in particular you would want to have your routes organized like this to begin:

```
Route::get('/addClickBanner/{id_banner}','PagesController@SomeStaticString');
Route::get('someStaticString/{main_category}/{slug}','PagesController@getArticle')->where('main_category', '^(?!SomeStaticString$).*');
```

Comment: Great explanation